# DIN rail-mount on/off switch or toggle button

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, switches, circuit-breaker

I want to manually flip a switch to connect and disconnect a 10 μF capacitor from my microcontroller's reset pin in my industrial application where everything is mounted on DIN rails. The cap is already in its own DIN rail-mount housing, but it draws very little current at a low voltage.

I thought it would be easy to simply use a low-current breaker, but even the 1 A model I found is not allowing the capacitor to charge at all. This literally can be the simplest of all electronic components: a switch, but I can't find anything low-profile that mounts on DIN rails. I had the idea to mount something like a rocker switch onto a DIN rail bracket, but I would prefer to buy an off-the-shelf unit.

[Breaker](https://www.sourceasi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/NDB2_datasheet.pdf) I bought that does not seem to work for this low-voltage, low-current, DC application:

[image: ASI NDB2-63C1-1 DIN Rail Mount Circuit Breaker]

Comment: you could try these "toggle" button relays in din format, these devices they use for lighting and so. they are plain mechanical relays with a slight twist so they don't use current during the on state.

Comment: Hi @NaturalDemon can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding an off the shelf solution (Part number ESG290T/2). The unit I purchased is assembled in the US. The original Nader switch was only about $10 so I was hoping to find something in the same price range but the  model I found is about 3X the price at $32. In this case I think the price is warranted because it is assembled locally by a small business. Here is the link if anyone happens to need one: https://esgllc-usa.com/product/toggle-switch-terminal-with-led/

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a DIN rail-mount enclosure for a few dollars and just drill out the front panel for a switch.  If you want to get really fancy, some manufacturers will sell a matching PCB that you can put a terminal block on.

Comment: This is a good idea but I was hoping to avoid a "manual" solution with multiple parts in case I need to make the unit another 10 or even 50 times. Even if it just takes 15 minutes to properly assemble 1 unit, doing that so many times would not be optimal.

Comment: If you search "DIN-Rail Mount Miniature Toggle Switches" you'll find some options.

Comment: thanks, I believe you had the solution, although pricey, that is exactly what I was looking for https://www.mcmaster.com/7218K24/ and https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/relays_-z-_timers/electro-mechanical_relays/51152?gclid=CjwKCAiA0JKfBhBIEiwAPhZXDzIZVRsAIt5ycENgohSHjTOHGNQGt-GzlNT2dyfJQP6zTttTk3dHIhoCGBgQAvD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

look for: bi stable relay, latching relay or maybe pulse relay, these are electromagnetically en don't consume power, a wheel with notches inside is rotated via a coil on a button push and makes or brakes the contact.